# Working with hex in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, hex, bit

I can not get simple thing to work in objective-c - just lack of experience. Maybe someone could point me in the right direction.

I have two `NSStrings`, in this format the information passes from other object. So in case of working with other formats (eg. `NSData`) I need to convert them. Yet, even converting to NSData I have no idea how to make it done.

```
NSString *year = @"FC"; ( 1111 1100 )
NSString minutes* = @"0"; ( 0000 0000 )
```

I need to cut first bits from `year` and add them to `minutes`. The result should be like this:

```
year = 3C ( 0011 1100 )
minutes = 30 ( 0011 0000 )
```

How should i do this ?

Comment: Why are you using strings for that? Using integers, that would be as simple as `minutes += year >> 6`.

Comment: Leave a comment for downvoting. H2CO3 you got the point, i would love to use casual shifts and && operations, yet I do not know how to convert NSString to such format properly.

Comment: You can use the `strtol()` family of functions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It did help me a lot in understanding how to work with hex in code, currently I only have understanding of computation on paper, so thanks a lot once more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to convert the strings to integers, use C standard library functions:

```
NSString *year = @"FC";
NSString *minutes = @"0";
int yearInt = strtol([year UTF8String], NULL, 16);
int minInt = strtol([minutes UTF8String], NULL, 16);

minInt += (year >> 6) & 0x03;
```

etc.